# Only 1 value of 2 values in an array are being returned from function in async/await function calls; getting uncaught promise error

Tags: javascript, async-await, dynamics-crm, webapi, dynamics-365

New to writing `async/await` functions in javascript.  I just can't seem to get these `async/await` keywords in the right place. The following code provides a function `maCreateWin911CcsTemplate(executionContext, id)` which creates an email record with a template in D365 CRM in which in turn calls another function `getNewestLicenseTrackingRecord(executionContext, maId)` that returns 2 values in an array I need to insert into the email record template passed through an action.

```
async function maCreateWin911CcsTemplate(executionContext, id)
{
    debugger;
    
    var formContext = executionContext;
    
    var maId = id;
    maId = maId.toString().replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
    
    var newestLtRecordSnAndLocation = new Array(2);
    newestLtRecordSnAndLocation = getNewestLicenseTrackingRecord(executionContext, maId);
    var sn = await newestLtRecordSnAndLocation[0];
    var sysLocation = newestLtRecordSnAndLocation[1];
        
        var parameters = {};
        parameters.sn = sn;
        parameters.sysLocation = sysLocation;
        
        var target = {entityType: "new_maintenancecontract", id: maId};
        parameters.entity = target;

            parameters.getMetadata = function () 
            {
                return {
                    boundParameter: "entity",
                    operationType: 0,
                    operationName: "new_MAActionCreateWIN911CCSEmail",
                    parameterTypes: 
                    {   
                        "sn": 
                        {
                            "typeName": "Edm.String",
                            "structuralProperty": 1
                        },
                        
                        "sysLocation": 
                        {
                            "typeName": "Edm.String",
                            "structuralProperty": 1
                        },  
                                        
                        "entity":
                        {
                            "typeName": "new_maintenancecontract",                  
                            "structuralProperty": 5
                        }
                    },
            
                };
            }
    
    Xrm.WebApi.online.execute(parameters).then(
        function success(result) {
            if(result.ok){
                result.json().then(function (results) {
                    
                    var emailId = results.emailId;
                    emailId = emailId.substring(61, 97);
                    Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("email",emailId);
            })
    }
    else
    {
          Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Unknown error occured in ISV code.");
    }
        },
    function (error) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
    }
);

}

function getNewestLicenseTrackingRecord(executionContext, maId)
{ 
    debugger;
    
    var executionContext = executionContext;
    
    var maId = maId;
    maId = maId.toString().replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
    
    parent.Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("new_license", "?$select=createdon,new_licenseno,new_systemlocation&$filter=_new_maid_value%20eq%20" + '<guid>' + "%20&$top=1&$orderby=createdon%20desc").then(
    function success(result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.entities.length; i++) {
            alert(result.entities[i].createdon + " : " + result.entities[i].new_licenseno + " : " + result.entities[i].new_systemlocation);
            
            
            if(result.entities[i].new_licenseno === null)
            {
                var licenseNo = "";
            }
            else
            {
                var licenseNo = result.entities[i].new_licenseno.toString();
            }
            
            if(result.entities[i].new_systemlocation === null)
            {
                var systemLocation = "";
            }
            else
            {
                var systemLocation = result.entities[i].new_systemlocation.toString();
            }
            var ltArray = new Array(2);
            ltArray = [licenseNo, systemLocation]; 
            return ltArray;
            //break; // just for code demo
        }
    },
        function(error) {  
            alert("Error: " + error.message);  
        }  
    );
    
}
```

As you can see from above, I am returning an array with 2 values in the `getNewestLicenseTrackingRecord(executionContext, maId)` however, one of the values is always returning undefined because of an uncaught promise as seen below:

[image]

I've been fighting with moving the `async/await` keywords around and have not been successful in getting both values.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The `getNewestLicenseTrackingRecord` doesn't return anything from its body. If you place a `return` in front of `parent.Xrm.WebApi` you'd get a value out of it. That value would be a promise, so you'd need to call it as `newestLtRecordSnAndLocation = await getNewestLicenseTrackingRecord(executionContext, maId);`

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks....giving it a go right now

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks alot. This did the trick. You want to write this up as an answer with a brief explanation on where/why to expose async/await in the functions so that future users may be helped, I will gladly mark your answer as answer